# Identifying long irregular patterns in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I have to identify the patterns that you can see in the example image.
I highlighted one of the patterns to detect in yellow (of course it should go from one side to the other of the image). Each pattern is formed by three lines.

As you can see there are many more with lots of irregularities (that I would like to follow). I highlighted with red circles some examples of problematic areas.

There is a lot of noise and possible false positives.

I am trying to remove the noise through some thresold processing, but it seem a little difficult. Edge detection does not work in this kind of application.

What do you think are the best techniques to do so?

[image: Sample image]

Thanks in advance for any answers.

EDIT:
Unedited image:
[image: Unedited]

Using erosion with an 1x10 kernel after rotating a bit the image seems a good way to reach what want to obtain:
[image: Eroded]

Comment: I am unclear as to whether you do, or do not, want to find the red areas. If not, what is wrong with them? Is the direction of the lines always the same, or could they run any direction? Are the lines always in threes or could there be 2, or 4 or 5?

Comment: The red areas present white zones that I am not interested in and could influence the processing. The lines I need are always in threes, like in the yellow example. In this image there are quite a few of them, and you can see that some of them follow much more irregular patterns.

Comment: Did you try hough line?

Comment: No, because I have to follow the irregular pattern of the "lines" as precisely as I can.

Comment: There exists a "line-scan" approach to this problem. If we assume you are able to initialise the beginning of each line, then you can scan a window in the direction you're interested in. As we are only interested in horizontal edges a kernel to only get those may be used. A "line" window (of width of 3-9 pixels wide), scanning from LHS to RHS (or in reverse) may be used to scan and detect the lines. If you know certain likes are more likely to be straight than others then you can use that information to increase robustness. Approximate number and spacing of lines if known will help in init.

Comment: The initialisation problem still exists, which you might have to do manually to begin with, during development at least whilst working on the tracking of multiple lines in the ROI/window. "Some initialisation method" may be run at the beginning as well as during the process at multiple stages during the horizontal scan. As long your SNR > 0.5 then there will be a positive correlation between locations of lines from the "initialisation" and where the "tracker" says they exist during the scan.

Comment: can you post original image without markers?

Comment: @FMarazzi why not Hough? you can use the ouput of Hough transform to get a rough estimate of the lines and then refine the detection as a second step.

Comment: Ok, I will try Hough as first step then.

Answer (score 0):

Hough Analysis seems to do a pretty reasonable job at getting started with this image. I am just using the command-line version from **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJuWo.jpg \
  \( +clone -canny 0x1+10%+30% -background none -fill red -stroke red -hough-lines 9x9+200 \) \
  -composite rectangle_hough.png
```

[image]